# save css on device to load it in offline mode

Tags: android, css, caching, webview, offline

I've got a lot of webViews in my app and want to cache them on device. Now I save the content as string in a SQLite Database and if theres no internetconnection, I load the text from there. But if somebody clean the Cache on the device, the pictures and css aren't there anymore.

Is there a simple way to cache all pictures and the css, which are/is linked on the page?

The link to the css is in the String I cached, therefore I have to manipulate this link before saving? But how? And what about the pictures?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public WebView webView;
    public Activity activity;
    public Context context;
    public String htmlData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        activity = this;
        context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (isOnline())
        {
            new CacheData().execute("");
        } else
        {
            WebCacheDataHandler wcdh = new WebCacheDataHandler(context);
            wcdh.open();
            String cache = wcdh.getContent();
            wcdh.close();
            webView.loadData(cache, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }

    public String getUrlContent(String url) throws IOException
    {
        URL oracle = new URL(url);
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(inputLine + "\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean isOnline()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public class CacheData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... string)
        {
            try
            {
                htmlData = getUrlContent("http://www.dumdidum.de/");
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isModified)
        {
            webView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            // write data in Database
            WebCacheDataHandler wcdh = new WebCacheDataHandler(context);
            wcdh.open();
            wcdh.insertCache(htmlData);
            wcdh.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use AppCache/Manifest ;)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to implement your own version of AppCache rather than use the one that's already there?

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand the way, which already exists: I don't want to use the HTML AppCache using the Manifest, because I don't want (and must not ;) ) manipulate something on the webserver. I think you mean something like this: http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html ?
edit: and it's not a webapp, I only show a lot of webviews

Comment: Maybe it's enough to know, how often the cache from the app will be cleaned and how I recognize, that it's cleaned. Then I could show my page correct in Offlinemode and if the cache is cleaned I'll show a message like this: "Sorry, there's no Internet connection and no data in the Cache for offline mode"